# Subdomain, htaccess Rewrite and masking URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Users on my site are creating their own pages, i want to make subdomain with redirect and masking real URL.

I have made RewriteRule:

`Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$

RewriteCond %1 !=www

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/site.php?site=%1 [QSA,R=302]`

When user enters:`subdomain.domain.com` he will be trasfered to php script witch finds ID by page name in DB and redirects to:
    `domain.com/workarea/pages/ID/index.html`

I wan't to mask real URL, just to show the URL with subdomain 
     `subdomain.domain.com`
but also i want to show all after `/` when user go to gallery or smth else, like:

`subdomain.domain.com/index.html

subdomain.domain.com/gallery.html`


but i don`t know how to do that.

I've tried to use `[P]` flag, but it just redirects to `domain.com`,
or it is just don`t let the php script to work.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, even if set up to have htaccess redirect a subdomain to php; the following remark:

> When user enters:subdomain.domain.com he will be trasfered to php
>   script witch finds ID by page name in DB and redirects to:
>   domain.com/workarea/pages/ID/index.html

Will ensure that your visitors will see `domain.com/workarea/pages/ID/index.html`, because - as you say - php redirects visitors to that page. If you want to show the htaccess "masked" url, you need to make sure PHP parses the required HTML and not redirect.

As to the "masked" redirection from htaccess. What is the current behavior?

Comment: i want to write secondary rule where user after entering address will see just the adress he wrote (subdomain.domain.com) and the address that remains after ID /index.html or gallery.html, aboutus.html and other, but the real address will be domain.com/workarea/pages/ID/index.html

Comment: That's what I said. No matter what you do your PHP is probably currently redirecting everything to that URL.

Comment: You're welcome. For you next visit/question: please format your question like this: "problem" - "expected behavior" - "current behavior". This way people trying to answer your question don't have to guess so much ;) Good luck with your application!